# Android Background Service

Tags: javascript, android, titanium, background-service, titanium-android

I want to use background Service in my Titanium Application.

I used every code which need to insert in Titanium Android application.

In TiApp.xml file : Register Service here

```js
<services>
    <service url='BGServ.js' type="interval"/>
</services>
```

Here "**BGServ.js**" file is placed in my **app/lib** folder.

---

In BGServ.js file : Our Service file code

```js
var service = Titanium.Android.currentService;
var intent = service.intent;
Ti.API.info('Background Service Started');
Ti.API.info('Background Service of Platform : ' + Titanium.Platform.osname + ' Started');

service.addEventListener('resume', function(e) {
 Titanium.API.info('Service code resumes, iteration ' + e.iteration);
});

service.addEventListener('pause', function(e) {
 Titanium.API.info('Service code pauses, iteration ' + e.iteration);
});
```

---

In index.js file : Here we creating Service Intent

```js
var intent = Titanium.Android.createServiceIntent({
 url : '/BGServ.js'
});
intent.putExtra('interval', 1000);
intent.putExtra('message_to_echo', 'Test Service');
Titanium.Android.startService(intent);
```

---

**Issue** : Android Service is not working in my project. In BGServ.js having a Ti.API.info() which also not printed in console. I am struct here help me.

TiSDK Version : 3.5.0 GA

Thanks,

**Abidhusain**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Found the Solution of Background Service for Android in Titanium Appcelerator**

> In TiApp.xml file :

```js
<services>
  <service type="interval" url="bg_service.js"/>
</services>
```

**Note** that here in url attribute no need to add **"\"** ahead of file name.

And also put Background Service file in only "**assets**" folder on your application.

> In "**bg_service.js**" file : Our Service file code

```js
var service = Titanium.Android.currentService;
var intent = service.intent;
Ti.API.info('Background Service Started');
Ti.API.info('Background Service of Platform : ' + Titanium.Platform.osname + ' Started');

service.addEventListener('resume', function(e) {
 Titanium.API.info('Service code resumes, iteration ' + e.iteration);
});

service.addEventListener('pause', function(e) {
 Titanium.API.info('Service code pauses, iteration ' + e.iteration);
});
```

> In Index.xml file : Here we creating intent and start background Service

```js
var intent = Titanium.Android.createServiceIntent({
  url : 'bg_service.js'
});
intent.putExtra('interval', BG_INTERVAL_SECONDS);

Titanium.Android.startService(intent);
```

**Note** that here in url attribute no need to add **"\"** ahead of file name.

```
Issue Resolved by above code and also take care of **"\"** in url attribute
```

If anyone found any other solution then replay here.

Thanks,

**Abidhusain**